# Remove all but 1 of the duplicates in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the duplicate values and leave only one occurrence of that value.

**Example:**

```
var myArray = ["blue","blue","red","red","green","blue","blue","red"];
//REMOVE DUPLICATES LEAVING ONE
//results in - myArray = ["blue","red","green"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter duplicates like this (used ES6 syntax):

```
const myArray = ["blue","blue","red","red","green","blue","blue","red"];

const result = myArray.filter((a, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(a) === i);

console.log(result);
```